# android java retrieve sharedpreferences in arraylist

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have wrote a little code to save new just added items to `sharedpreferences`. But if I retrieve the `sharedpreferences` in an arraylist it displays `{"todo":"new item" }` but I only want to display one item and only the text if you understand me. Here is my save `Arraylist` code:

```
public void saveArrayList(Context context ,ArrayList<DayItems> mlist){
    SharedPreferences shared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    shared = context.getSharedPreferences("MONDAY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = shared.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(mlist);
    editor.putString("mondAy", json);
    String getSaved = shared.getString("mondAy", null);
    Toast.makeText(PlannerActivity.this, getSaved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Here is my add item to arraylist:

```
@Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String afspraak = addTEXT.getText().toString().trim();
                                    if(afspraak.length()>0){
                                        addTEXT.setText("");
                                        mon.add(new DayItems(afspraak));
                                        dayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //save arraylist with new item
                                        saveArrayList(context, mon);
                                    }

                                }
                            });
```

Actually what I want is a snippet to retrieve `SharedPreferences`.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to retrieve from **SharedPreferences**

```
    List<DayItems> listDayItems = gson.fromJson(shared.getString("mondAy", null), new TypeToken<List<DayItems>>() {
        }.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely works with your condition:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, null);

Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayObject>>() {}.getType();

ArrayList<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will definitely try this one out!

Comment: Thanks @svenvdz to fast Response as we gave you to reply your post. Thanks Again